# Search two columns in Microsoft excel 2013 and set the value of a third column with a specific value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to search a specific text which is the `firstname_lastname` e.g `John_Smith` in `worksheetA`. `WorksheetA` has a column `firstname` and another column `lastname`. So after knowing which row has the firstname and lastname I searched for, I want to set the value of cell in the same row with a specific value.

For example if this is my worksheet:

```
Firstname     Lastname     Found
Matt          Damon        No
Smith         Andrew       No
John          Smith        No
Tom           Mark         No
```

and my search word is `John_Smith` the result will be

```
Firstname     Lastname     Found
Matt          Damon        No
Smith         Andrew       No
John          Smith        Yes
Tom           Mark         No
```

Any advice please how this can be done in VBA excel?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The simplest way to do this is probably with a helper column.  Combine first and last name in a new column and then search there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
Public Sub searchfullname()
    fullname = InputBox("Input first and last name separated by _")
    namesarray = Split(fullname, "_")
    i = 2
    dataintable = True
    result = "No"
    m = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
    If m = "" Then dataintable = False
    While dataintable = True
        result = "No"
        If m = namesarray(0) Then
            n = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
            If n = namesarray(1) Then
                result = "Yes"
            End If
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) = result
        i = i + 1
        m = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
        If m = "" Then dataintable = False
    Wend
End Sub
```